# what is fastest way for Visual-C++ DLL to copy 2-3Mega-Bytes to a C# buffer?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

And what kind of C# buffer can handle this?

I need my C# solution .exe to get about 2-3MB of data, up to 60 times a second, from a Visual-C++ DLL that is generating live video frames (up to 60/second) and copying it to the C# buffer.  C# will then forward this data through USB to another computer.

I've tried C# String but there's a maximum size limit (roughly around 10KB).

I'm thinking of a C# struct containing the data buffer plus handshake variables.

Possibly, I will need multiple buffers, so maybe will need an array of these structs.

But, essentially, what's the best way (fastest!!!) to give DLL destination address of some kind of C# buffer, so that DLL can copy its 2-3MB of generated data to the buffer, and then set a variable flag, meanwhile C# is polling this flag to know when data is in buffer, so it can be further processed.

Buffer should be first created by C#, not DLL, I think.

Comment: Personally, I would use a memory mapped file in conjunction with a signalling mechanism like a named event. [See MSDN here for starters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx)

Comment: You're talking sending up to 180 MB/sec across a USB port? That's within the capability of USB 3.0, although your throughput will probably be limited by the speed of the receiving device. You might also have some trouble trying to render 60 fps of uncompressed images.

Comment: "C# String" does  not have a max size limit of around 10KB under any circumstance. Where did you get that impression?

Comment: Ken: When I use C# String that's 200KB or bigger, return from DLL call causes this popup error:  "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred in VNGuideView.exe

Additional information: Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Internal limitation: structure is too complex or too large."

Comment: Jim:  Actually sending through USB to iPad, which is USB v2.0 (480Mbps = 60-MB/sec).  60fps is ideal max, and we can reduce if need be.

Comment: The pinvoke marshaller puts a limit on the size of the object it is willing to marshal, 64KB.  Which you don't want anyway, perf is out of the window when the marshaller needs to copy the data instead of just generating a pointer to pinned memory.  The question is too vague to give specific advice.  But a plain byte[] will work fine.  You'll get the pinning for free since it is allocated in the large object heap.

Comment: @DouglasK.Bell: But 60 frames of 2-3 MB each is 120 to 180 MB/sec: two or three times the speed of USB 2.0.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the subject of video processing, but surely there's some suitable frame atropy video compression algorithm in existence for this scenario.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Yes -- even motion-JPEG can reduce the bandwidth requirements quite a bit (and since it's pretty much just JPEG, it's easy to find libraries for it, etc.)

Comment: Jim: Worst case frame is 512x512 pixels x 24bits-per-pixel = 6.3Mbits... X 60fps = 377Mbps.  USB v2.0 rate is 480Mbps (Wikipedia) for 78% utilization of USB bandwidth. Won't need compression (is dedicated system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea:

1. Have the C# code allocate the buffer
2. Pin it to a fixed address
3. Pass the pointer to the C++ code
4. The C++ code can now directly write to the buffer (maybe even using a zero-copy approach)

Advantage is that you can use a normal, managed `byte[]`.

Comment: Yes, zero-copy is the way.  So far, I allocate buffer on C++ side, then on C# side, within unsafe{}, convert to byte*.  Still need to 'connect' to rest of code.  If it works, I'll post solution here.